# How do I create a variable in Smarty and fill this variable with html code?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

**Question:**
How do I create a variable in Smarty and fill this variable with html code?

**Situation:**
I need to re use a certain big html part a few times, I dont want to put it in a different file and extend that file, but in a variable. I have tried doing it with javascript, php and smarty but it just wont work.

I need everything inside of the foreach inside a variable to re use. So everything from `{if $aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr|strstr:"A2"}`to.... `{/if}`

Also, the `'A2'` will become `'A'+$etages`, `$etages` being a existing variable

EDIT: 
I think the best way to handle this is with jquery but I dont know how. Because when $etages changes the table has to change aswell. So when $etages is 2 the table can only show $aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr that starts with A2. and when $etages becomes 3, the table has to change again.

Also, how can I make this work since $etages is a int and the 'A' is a string?

```
{if $aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr|strstr:"A"+$etages}
```

**Code/ Html:**

```
<tbody>
{foreach $aWoningen as $aWoning}
{if $aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr|strstr:"A2"}
    <tr class="bouwnummer-table-row">
        <td>{$aWoning.Woning_Bouwnr}</td>
        <td>{$aWoning.Projectwoning_Titel}</td>
        <td>{$aWoning.Woning_WoonOpp} m&sup2;</td>
        <td>{$aWoning.Woning_Adres|escape}</td>
        <td>
            {if $aWoning.Woning_Prijs!=0}
                {if $aWoning.Verkocht!=1}
                    {$aWoning.Woning_Prijs|escape:"html"|lv_hele_euro}
                {else}
                    Verkocht
                {/if}
            {else}
                n.n.b.
            {/if}
        </td>
        <td class="{if $aWoning.Verkocht==1}status-verkocht{elseif $aWoning.Optie==1}status-optie{else}status-beschikbaar{/if}">
            <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
            {if $aWoning.Verkocht==1}
                Verkocht
            {elseif $aWoning.Optie==1}
                In Optie
            {else}
                Beschikbaar
            {/if}
        </td>
    </tr>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a new HTML-file and include it?

Comment: Because of a reason I cant really explain, Ill try to explain in a edit

Comment: Have you tried with ajax? make it call a php file that processes the template with the parameters you post to it

Answer (score 0):

{assign} is used for assigning template variables during the execution of a template.

Ex: {assign var="name" value="Bob"}

Refer this URL for more details [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)